# How to build a java swing application in intelijidea

Tags: build, intellij-idea

How to build a java swing application which developed in intelij idea with it's dependencies.

Comment: Do you think for distribution?

Answer (score 8):

1. New Project
2. Create project from scratch
3. Select type: Java Module
4. File -> New
5. GUI Form

You'll see their UI Editor pop up.

You'll need to read up on javax.swing on how to start your application though. That piece is not specific to IntelliJ IDEA.